# PrimeFaces, LineChart and null values

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm using PrimeFaces 6.2 and I'm using the [line charts](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/chart/line.xhtml)

Everything is working fine except when in my data, there're some missing points.
For example in front of this data

```
[year;value] 
[2016;10] 
[2017;null] 
[2018;20]
```

the chart is not displayed at all.
I'm using a LineChartModel without any customization except the title.
For the code you can refer to the [prime faces showcase](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/chart/line.xhtml), that's very clear.

Can Prime Faces makes some kind of interpolation in order to manage the holes in the data?

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem in BarChartModel. It got resolved after I initialized all the missing values with zero(0).

Comment: Correct. There are 'duplicates' of this Q/A though. In Stackoverflow it is good practice to find these and mark this new question as a duplicate via the close button below the question